# Laravel Apache URL mapping

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mapping

I currently use laravel 5 for web development. And my goal is to upload the website which I made in laravel to a shared host.

But if I upload my files to the public_html folder, I'll have to navigate to `mywebsite.com/public/mypage` to access a route `mypage`. Which is not what I want.

I would have just changed the the name of public folder to public_html and then shifted all other folders to the root directory and changed some laravel config options, but that would have made my root directory unclean. So think I would have to use .htaccess for what I want. I am not familiar in using .htaccess, so how would I do this:

If the user enters `mywebsite.com/mypage` in the browser he gets to see the page `mywebsite.com/public/mypage` in the browser, but the url in the browser stays the same.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem when hosting my website in shared hosting godaddy.

I also used laravel5 frameowork and launched the site http://www.hahafunnyjokes.com

Edit the .htaccess file in the root folder where your public_html pointing

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
      RewriteRule (.*) http://www.examplecom/$1 [R=301,L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Thats it, I got my site up and running.
Replace example.com with your website name

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It worked. But one more thing, is this safe? Can any hacker get into my site using some '..' in the url? Or does laravel take care of that?